# ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index- scipy fsolve

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe with columns Date, cash, rate, name. When I try to run the below mentioned code I get error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index". Also it gives warning as "RuntimeWarning: The number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 400."
How can I solve this error ?

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
def xnpv(rate, values, dates):
    if rate <= -1.0:
        return float('inf')
    d0 = dates.min()   # or min(dates)
    return sum([ vi / (1.0 + rate)**((di - d0).days / 365.0) for vi, di in zip(values, dates)])
def xirr(values, dates):
    try:
        return scipy.optimize.newton(lambda r: xnpv(r, values, dates), 0.0)
    except RuntimeError:    # Failed to converge?
        return fsolve(lambda r: xnpv(r, values, dates), 3)   #error comes from here
def f(x):

    x["XNPV"] = xnpv(0.1, x["Cash"], x['Date'])
    x["XIRR"] = xirr( x["Cash"], x['Date'])
    return x

f2 = f1.groupby('RATE').apply(f)
```

Comment: which line gives error? there will be a line # printed.

Comment: when I want to run XIRR part then it gives error. when I run the command where I groupby, there function call takes place and that goes to xirr function and at return fsolve line it gives error